# Can not initiate activity from GCMIntentService.class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a GCMIntentService class, in which i get some messages returned from my server. I want to be able to start a certain activity when a certain message arrives at my app. For example if in my onMessage() method (onMethod() is the method, and the first place, in the app, that receives the messages from the server) arrives the string = "tomatoe", i want to start a specific activity. The way i know right now to start an activity, is this:

```
Intent resactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResponseActivity.class);
            resactivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(resactivity);
```

The problem is that GCMIntentService, is not a class that extends activity, and i believe that i can't use this code for this purpose. Is there some way to initiate an activity from a class that is not an activity, by creating an intent inside that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the method I usually use to start an activity when a notification arrives in my apps. Take a look to all the configurations and remove those you are not interested in:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String app_name = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    String message =  intent.getStringExtra("payload");
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
    int icono = R.drawable.ic_stat_notify;
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icono, app_name, time);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ResponseActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, app_name, message, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> The problem is that GCMIntentService, is not a class that extends activity, and i believe that i can't use this code for this purpose.

`GCMIntentService` inherits from `Context`, which is where `startActivity()` is defined.

Bear in mind, though, that your users may attack you with pitchforks or machine guns for popping up activities at random points in time, perhaps in the middle of something else that they are doing. Please make this behavior configurable, or else make very very certain that your users will appreciate these interruptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it as such:
    getApplication().startActivity(resactivity);